# Precision setting lost when postprocessing rows

Tags: tables, pgfplotstable

I want to generate a formatted table from a CSV file:

- with every other row in a different color
- using 4 digits precision for numbers

Right now I can't seem to have both.

Here's an example code to illustrate my issue:

test.csv

```
a,b,c
d,0.4897844135,0.489789797
e,0.4897844135,0.489789797
f,0.4897844135,0.489789797
```

test.tex

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}


  \pgfplotstabletypeset[
    dec sep={$,$},
    col sep=comma,
    columns={a,b,c},
    columns/a/.style={string type, column type={|c}},
    columns/b/.style={precision=4, column type={|c}},
    columns/c/.style={precision=4, column type={|c|}},
    every head row/.style={before row=\hline,after row=\hline},
    every row/.style={after row=\hline},
    every last row/.style={after row=\hline},
    postproc cell content/.code={
        \ifodd\pgfplotstablerow\relax
        \else
            % ah - an even row number.
            % ah - introduce a cell color:
            \pgfkeysalso{@cell content={\cellcolor[gray]{0.9}#1}}%
        \fi
    }
    ,]{test.csv}
  }


\end{document}
```

Output:
[image: Illustration]

Note that I also lose my decimal separator setting.

What should I add to my code to make it behave the way I want?

Should I use another package/syntax to achieve the result I expect? I'm open to using any other package that would achieve the same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By setting `\pgfkeysalso{@cell content={\cellcolor[gray]{0.9}#1}}%` you're overwriting the cell content that PGFPlotstable generated (the `#1` only refers to the raw value of the cell, not the rounded output). You only need to add the `\cellcolor[gray]{0.9}` command to the cell content but leave the rest unchanged. You can do that using the key

```
\pgfkeysalso{@cell content/.prefix={\cellcolor[gray]{0.9}}}%
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}


  \pgfplotstabletypeset[
    dec sep={$,$},
    col sep=comma,
    columns={a,b,c},
    columns/a/.style={string type, column type={|c}},
    columns/b/.style={precision=4, column type={|c}},
    columns/c/.style={precision=4, column type={|c|}},
    every head row/.style={before row=\hline,after row=\hline},
    every row/.style={after row=\hline},
    every last row/.style={after row=\hline},
    postproc cell content/.code={
        \ifodd\pgfplotstablerow\relax
        \else
            % ah - an even row number.
            % ah - introduce a cell color:
            \pgfkeysalso{@cell content/.prefix={\cellcolor[gray]{0.9}}}%
        \fi
    }
    ,]{
a,b,c
d,0.4897844135,0.489789797
e,0.4897844135,0.489789797
f,0.4897844135,0.489789797    
    }


\end{document}
```

Comment: This works but I just realized this broke the horizontal centering of the table allowing it to be outside document margins I achiever using `\centerline{}` around the table. Any explanation/workaround for this?

Comment: @nicoco: I can't reproduce that issue. You could try using the `\centering` command instead, but if that doesn't work you might have to open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Jake's answer was correct, but I ended up doing things slightly differently and figured I'll share:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\begin{document}
text
\begin{table}[!h]
\center

  \pgfplotstabletypeset[
    dec sep={$,$},
    col sep=comma,
    columns={a,b,c},
    columns/a/.style={string type, column type={c}},
    columns/b/.style={precision=5, column type={c}},
    columns/c/.style={precision=5, column type={c}},
    every even row/.style={before row={\rowcolor{blue!10}}},
    every odd row/.style={before row={\rowcolor{blue!3}}},
    ,]{
    a,b,c
    d,0.4897844135,0.489789797
    e,0.4897844135,0.489789797
    f,0.4897844135,0.489789797    
    }

\caption{Blah blah blah}
\end{table}
text
\end{document}
```

As you can see the syntax is more understandable like this.